# What's the best way to resize an image proportionally without creating whitespace?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can proportionally resize an image like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div style="height: 500px;">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/500/500">
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
img {
    max-width: 100%; 
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xxgxv/)**

When you reduce the window size horizontally the image gets smaller but it creates whitespace below.

How can I prevent this from happening, preferably with only CSS or if not with as little JS as possible?

To give you an idea if you are not sure, it has been done on [this site](http://www.alta.co.nz/) but with jquery plugin

Anyway I look forward to your answers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you're looking for `background-size: cover`. This will stretch an image to fully cover a given element.

```
div {
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/500/500);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center top;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/pNyGC/ for a demo of the effect.

Comment: Set it on the body background. Make sure your document is as high as the window.